# Using blogger I get an empty directory when accessing the domain without www

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I have set-up a redirect from sokodpsenicnetrave.blogspot.com to sokodpsenicnetrave.com.

When I access the site using http://sokodpsenicnetrave.com/ I get `Index of /`. Howeever, when using http://www.sokodpsenicnetrave.com/ I get back the regular website.

In blogger, I tried to resolve the question by activating "Redirect sokodpsenicnetrave.com to www.sokodpsenicnetrave.com", but it didn't work. How can I make my page redirect with and without www.?

Comment: Have you tried to google the problem? When I do I get a number of relevant search results, e.g. https://www.supportivehands.net/blogger-domain-not-working-without-www/

Comment: For the webserver that are fully different sites so you get differnt results.

Comment: The problem is the web server configuration. **domain.com** and **www.domain.com** is not the same for a web server. Most people configure the web server to point both to the same directory. In your case this is not the case.

Comment: Please note I edited your question quite extensively. I tried to improve the question title and make the question clearer to the audience of SO. Hope this helps to attract appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your domain properly. At the moment they point to different IP addresses. So you need to configure sokodpsenicnetrave.com to point to 173.194.65.121

```
ping www.sokodpsenicnetrave.com
PING ghs.l.google.com (173.194.65.121) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ee-in-f121.1e100.net (173.194.65.121): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=33.8 ms


ping sokodpsenicnetrave.com
PING sokodpsenicnetrave.com (198.23.57.44) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hosted.by.liquidnetlimited.com (198.23.57.44): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=124 ms
```

Comment: A `dig a www.sokodpsenicnetrave.com +short` is much cooler than a ping ;-)

Comment: In the last hour I pinging www.sokodpsenicnetrave.com - pings are different [64.233.167.121] [64.233.166.121] [173.194.66.121] [74.125.195.121] [74.125.206.121]. You sad that I need to point 173.194.65.121

Comment: Looks like you have to ask your hosting provider for some clues. If  IPs are changing it might mean there are some load balancing going on or whatnot ...

Answer (score 0):

I contacted hosting provider (as zzart suggested) and he made changes.
He write

> Trouble is that you have pointed domain and its www subdomain to
>   different locations:
>
> ```
> ~ $ host sokodpsenicnetrave.com
> sokodpsenicnetrave.com has address 198.23.57.44
> sokodpsenicnetrave.com mail is handled by 10 mbox.freehostia.com.
>
> ~ $ host www.sokodpsenicnetrave.com
> www.sokodpsenicnetrave.com is an alias for ghs.google.com.
> ghs.google.com is an alias for ghs.l.google.com.
> ghs.l.google.com has address 74.125.136.121
> ghs.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4013:c00::79
> ```
>
> I have setup in your account with us custom .htaccess file via File
>   Manager menu to redirect traffic domain sokodpsenicnetrave.com to
>   www.sokodpsenicnetrave.com Now both options will load only one
>   website.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect your "naked domain" to www domain, make sure you have pointing the domain correctly.

Go to your domain panel, then follow this setup.

set your domain `A Record` to blogger IP address.

```
sokodpsenicnetrave.com    216.239.38.21
sokodpsenicnetrave.com    216.239.36.21
sokodpsenicnetrave.com    216.239.34.21
sokodpsenicnetrave.com    216.239.32.21
```

then point a `CNAME` to google name alias

```
www.sokodpsenicnetrave.com    ghs.google.com
```